# SQL Add columns based on value from another column

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have a table like this:

| id | cols | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | date | 01-01-01 |
| 1 | name | abc |
| 1 | flag | True |
| 1 | end_date | null |
| 2 | date | 01-01-02 |
| 2 | name | abcd |
| 2 | flag | False |
| 2 | end_date | 01-01-03 |

And I need to create a table that looks like

| id | date | name | flag | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-01 | abc | True | null |
| 2 | 01-01-02 | abcd | False | 01-01-03 |

I can use select/with only. No functions or create/update

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting technique to remember is that you can use `MAX(CASE WHEN...` on text values to achieve results like this:

```
SELECT id
, MAX(CASE WHEN cols = 'date' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS dt
, MAX(CASE WHEN cols = 'name' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS nm
, MAX(CASE WHEN cols = 'flag' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS flag
, MAX(CASE WHEN cols = 'end_date' THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS end_date
FROM #t
GROUP BY id
```

I've tried to avoid using SQL keywords as column names, so you have `dt` and `nm` instead of `date` and `name`.

You will probably want to apply some type casting as well to get it into a more usable format.

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3eebd8741eee08bed50c94c1b10ab31c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PIVOT and UNPIVOT relational operators to change a table-valued expression into another table. PIVOT rotates a table-valued expression by turning the unique values from one column in the expression into multiple columns in the output.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

U can use this query pivot it table value

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.cols) 
            FROM yourtablename c
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Id, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select id
                    ,val
                from yourtablename
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 val
                for cols in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query);
```